# In mIRC (internet relay chat) and IRcap, hide channels I'm joined to in status windows

Tags: privacy, irc, chat, users, status

I use mIRC and IRcap and I'm interested in not showing the channels I am joined to, to other users in their (mIRC/IRcap) status windows, is there any configuration I can use to accomplish this? Or using a command, script or add-on?

I would like to keep an anonymous state by the moment in order not be disturbed by other users.

Comment: I updated your question, please check whether it still accurately describes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What other users can see about you isn’t controlled by your client but by the IRC server. You can change this (sometimes) by adjusting your *user mode*. For example, [Rizon](https://wiki.rizon.net/index.php?title=User_Modes) offers the following user mode:

> p – private – Hides your non-common channels, as well as your sign-on and idle time in a `/whois yourNick`.

On [Libera Chat](https://libera.chat/guides/usermodes) it’s different, here we have this one:

> i – invisible – Hides you from global `WHO` by normal users, and shows only shared channels in `/WHOIS` output.

You must find the correct mode for the IRC network(s) you use. You can add it to the on-connect script (“perform”) to enable it automatically.

Comment: about "You must find the correct mode for the IRC network(s) you use. You can add it to the on-connect script (“perform”) to enable it automatically." you mean there is a script called "on-connect" where is this script located?, would you mind to give some exaple how to do this, thank you

Comment: It’s in the [mIRC Options](https://www.mirc.com/help/html/index.html?connect_options.html). If I remember correctly, it’s just a text box where you put the command. Like `/mode yourNick +i`. I no longer use mIRC so I don’t have anything more specific, sorry.